# how can i import an existing site's user table, where password not encrypted?

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, encryption

I have an existing site, which is okay, but due to cms feature I want to convert existing php site to word-press. My problem is that how can i keep alive existing users data like user-id and password in word-press user table ?? the passwords are not in wp format, but I want the existing users 
also remain there.

please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- it's just the password you're having problems with, and
- you're not using a custom `wp_check_password` function

you should be able to get away with setting it using the mysql `md5()` function.  It'll get updated to use a PHPass hash the first time the user logs in, but that shouldn't be a problem.

The code in question is in `wp_check_password` in [wp-includes/pluggable.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1452) - it includes the comment:

```
// If the hash is still md5...
```